# Combining the Output of "Replicates"

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
fn <- function()
{ i = 1:100
v1 = rnorm(100,100,100)
v2 = rnorm(100,100,100)
out = data.frame(i, v1,v2)
return(out)
}
```

**My Question:** I want to use the `replicate()` function in R to run this function 100 times and combine the output of all 100 runs into a single output (i.e. 3 columns, 100x100 = 10000 rows):

```
output = replicate(100, fn())
```

When I do this, the data comes out in some other format:

```
   [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]       
i  integer,100 integer,100 integer,100 integer,100 integer,100 integer,100 integer,100
v1 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100
v2 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100 numeric,100
```

I know that I can perform this exact same task with a FOR LOOP - but is there any way I can do this with the `replicate()` function?

In reality, I have a very large function which I don't want to modify with "i" and "j" indices  - I thought perhaps I could place the `replicate()` into a loop itself?

```
my_list = list()

for ( i in 1:100)
{

out_i = replicate(fn(),1)
out_i$round = i
my_list[i] = out_i
}

final <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)
```

But I am not sure how to do this - can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Note: Is this correct?

```
my_list <- lapply(1:100, function(i) {
    out_i <- fn()
    out_i$round <- i
    out_i
})

final <- do.call(rbind, my_list)

#### alternate method

my_list <- lapply(1:100, function(i) { 
  out_i <- my_function()
  out_i$lapply_index <- i 
  out_i
})

final <- do.call(rbind, my_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question, it says "is there any way I can do this with the replicate() function?". Here is my suggestion.

```
a=replicate(100, list(fn()))
```

a[[1]] returns the first results

Answer (score 4):

Use `simplify=FALSE` and then `do.call(rbind, ..)`:

```r
### does not work
output <- replicate(2, mtcars[1:2,])
output
#      [,1]      [,2]     
# mpg  numeric,2 numeric,2
# cyl  numeric,2 numeric,2
# disp numeric,2 numeric,2
# hp   numeric,2 numeric,2
# drat numeric,2 numeric,2
# wt   numeric,2 numeric,2
# qsec numeric,2 numeric,2
# vs   numeric,2 numeric,2
# am   numeric,2 numeric,2
# gear numeric,2 numeric,2
# carb numeric,2 numeric,2

### does work
output <- replicate(2, mtcars[1:2,], simplify = FALSE)
output
# [[1]]
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# [[2]]
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
output <- do.call(rbind, output)
output
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4       21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag   21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX41      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag1  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: r2evans: Thank you for your answer! I tried to solve it myself as well (see answer below) - is this correct? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob, you will find that `replicate(100, expr, simplify=FALSE)` and `lapply(1:100, function(ign) expr)` return identical objects. The differences are truly minor: (1) the `expr`ession does not need to be a function in `replicate`, less typing; (2) the use of `replicate` is more declarative, stating to the user/reader/world that you intend to do the same exact thing `n`-times without external variation, while `lapply(.., function(z) ...)` implies you should be doing something with `z`. While it's perfectly fine to ignore `z`, the future-you might thank your transparency.

Comment: Side note: if you're ever going to do this programmatically/unsupervised, there is one more difference: if `n=0`, then the results of `replicate(.)` and `lapply(.)` will be different, since `1:n` is going to return a vector of length 2, counter to what one might assume. In those cases, you can still use the `lapply` variant but using the safer `lapply(seq_len(n),  ..)` which will do _nothing_ when `n=0` as one might intend; `replicate(n,..)` will also do nothing in that case (without the need for `seq_len(n)`, of course).